# Bootstrap nav dropdown menu toggle issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a nav menu with bootstrap nav. I have added a small jquery code when i press mobile toggle menu it will close automatically and go destination

but if i have drop down menu in nav. this drop menu now not working. when i press dropdown menu parent for expand its close the menu automatically. and i cant check which menu available in drop down menu
so i have tried to add a condition. but its not working.

in dropdown menu parent have class called .dropdown-toggle. if this class available it shouldn't be close automatically

```
if (jQuery(".navbar-collapse a").val() !== '.dropdown-toggle') {
    jQuery('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {
        jQuery('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
    });
}
```

And here the html code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your parent menu item will work and as well as mobile menu toggle

```
 <script>
 (function($) {
 jQuery(function($) {
 $('.navbar .dropdown').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideToggle();
  }, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
  $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {   

    location.href = this.href;
  });
  });
  })(jQuery);
  </script>
```